Call to undefined method ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous() - Laravel 11, PHP 8.2
I'm having an interesting issue with my Laravel set up.
Anytime I run artisan or related command, it returns the error:
Call to undefined method ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous()

  at project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:708
    704▕      */
    705▕     protected function getClassForCallable($callback)
    706▕     {
    707▕         if (is_callable($callback) &&
  ➜ 708▕             ! ($reflector = new ReflectionFunction($callback(...)))->isAnonymous()) {
    709▕             return $reflector->getClosureScopeClass()->name ?? false;
    710▕         }
    711▕ 
    712▕         return false;

      +3 vendor frames 

  4   project/artisan:51
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::terminate(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput))

I am running Laravel 11 and Php 8.2.21 (Confirmed using php -v).
Update
This is being run using a docker utility container with command:
docker compose run --rm artisan migrate

As this is working within a docker environment.
Below is my docker-compose file:
services:
  # Nginx Service
  server:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
      - redis

  # PHP Service
  php:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com:delegated
    depends_on:
      - transaction-queue-worker
      - transaction-batch-queue-worker
      - sms-queue-worker
      - email-queue-worker

  # MySQL Service
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql.env
    # For development. DB should not be open to the public on production.
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./databases/mysql:/var/lib/mysql

  # Redis Service
  redis:
    image: redis:6
    volumes:
      - ./databases/redis:/data

  # Composer Service
  composer:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com

  # Artisan Service
  artisan:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com
    entrypoint: [ "php", "/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com/artisan" ]

  # Transaction Queue Worker Service
  transaction-queue-worker:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com
    entrypoint: [ "php", "/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com/artisan" ]
    command: queue:work --queue=transactionsQueue --sleep=3 --max-time=3600
    restart: always

  # Transaction Batch Queue Worker Service
  transaction-batch-queue-worker:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com
    entrypoint: [ "php", "/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com/artisan" ]
    command: queue:work --queue=transactionBatchQueue --sleep=3 --max-time=3600
    restart: always

  # SMS Queue Worker Service
  sms-queue-worker:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com
    entrypoint: [ "php", "/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com/artisan" ]
    command: queue:work --queue=smsQueue --sleep=3 --max-time=3600
    restart: always

  # Email Queue Worker Service
  email-queue-worker:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./applications/engine.sppaygh.com:/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com
    entrypoint: [ "php", "/var/www/html/engine.sppaygh.com/artisan" ]
    command: queue:work --queue=emails --sleep=3 --max-time=3600
    restart: always


Additionally below is my php.dockerfile :
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql


I check my php version using the command
docker compose run --rm php --version

The result is as such:
PHP 8.2.21 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jul 23 2024 03:09:29)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.21, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies

Thank you all for your help!

php -v can only be used to check the CLI. You need to check that PHP 8.2 is running on the web server. It is a common mistake to have different versions on the CLI and the web server.

@puklipo artisan commands are run on the command line.

What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How exactly do you run the command?

Hi @NicoHaase, I have updated the question to mention that this is being run using a docker utility container as well as the command.

how did you confirm you are running php8.2?

Sounds like PHP 8.2 is not the default PHP version in your container. But as you haven't shared any more details about this, it's impossible to tell why this happens and how that could be resolved

Hi @krisgjika I used the php container that processes requests to check using --version.

@NicoHaase Please let me know what information could be helpful so i provide that.

@krisgjika I have updated the question to include more details on my docker setup

This issue occurs because the ReflectionFunction::isAnonymous() method is not available in your PHP version. Ensure you are using PHP 8.1 or higher, as isAnonymous() was introduced in PHP 8.1.
Upgrade your PHP version to 8.1 or higher.

"isAnonymous() was introduced in PHP 8.1" No, in 8.2.

"Ensure you are using PHP 8.1 or higher" - sounds strange, as the OP already wrote that they are using PHP 8.2.21
